# WPF: How do I bind to property located down the visual tree of an adjacent control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF `Window` and `UserControl` which I use inside the `Window`

**Window:**

```
<Window x:Class="AdjacentControlVisualTree.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdjacentControlVisualTree"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:AdjacentControl x:Name="AdjacentControl"/>
        <Button Content="Foo"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AdjacentControl.BarDataGrid}"
            Command="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="AdjacentControlVisualTree.AdjacentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdjacentControlVisualTree">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:AdjacentViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="BarDataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="String" Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, the thing is, that I would like to pass `SelectedItem` property of `DataGrid` inside the *AdjacentControl* to the *FooCommand* command but the binding always passes null:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AdjacentControl.BarDataGrid}"
```

Is there a way how to make the binding work without having to change the structure of the controls?

Comment: The UserControl has to expose a dedicated property that you would bind to. As a note, a UserControl should *never* explicitly set its own DataContext as you do in its XAML. If you do that, you won't be able to use standard DataContext-based Bindings on its properties.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have this UserControl at all, instead of directly using a DataGrid in MainWindow?

Comment: This is a really lightweight example I have put together in order to prove to myself that it is indeed not working as I would expect and that it is not caused by something I might have overlooked in the pile of markup in my real solution.
I assumed that if I can bind to a property of an ancestor control's `DataContext` then it would be also possible to bind to child controls living inside another ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably most simply way would be to expose `BarDataGrid` as a property.

Change the XAML name (e.g. to `x:Name="barDataGrid"`) and add this property to the UserControl's code behind:

```
public DataGrid BarDataGrid { get { return barDataGrid; } }
```

Then bind to the DataGrid's SelectedItem property like this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding BarDataGrid.SelectedItem, ElementName=AdjacentControl}"
```

---

A cleaner solution would be not to expose the DataGrid child, but only its SelectedItem, by means of a dedicated dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedItemProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(AdjacentControl));

public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```

You would bind the DataGrid's SelectedItem to this property by a RelativeSource Binding

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

and bind the CommandParameter like this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AdjacentControl}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!
However, to be completely fair, I have to confess I completely forgot to mention that I would very much like to have a MVVM-compliant solution and having anything in the code behind certainly does not go well with the MVVM principles, if I understand it correctly.
Right now, I am a bit confused, because it might just seem that sometimes following the so-called *best practices* could lead to pitfalls one would not stumble upon, when not abiding by the rules so strictly.
Anyway, this seems as a nice enough solution when considering my case so thanks again... :)

Comment: @valachovicdom "*having anything in the code behind certainly does not go well with the MVVM principles*" is a common misconception. Especially when it comes to custom controls. They never have their own view models, but instead expose properties. Which are of course declared in their code behind. You may easily verify that by taking a look at the source code of the WPF framework controls. There is *a lot* of code behind, but not a single view model.